# How to create a popup when button is pushed in Android?

Tags: android

How can I create a custom popup class that accepts a simple string message? Im new to Android and help with code will be appreciated.

When a button is pushed in the main layout, the popup must pop up on the screen.

**Custom popup class**

```
public class CustomPopup extends PopupWindow {

    private String message;
    private Double anchorX;
    private Double anchorY;

    PopupWindow popup;

    public CustomPopup(String message) {
        super();
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void showPopup(Activity context) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
}
```

**Main Class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText messageTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageTxt);
        Button generateBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.generateBtn);

        String message = messageTxt.getText().toString();

        final CustomPopup popup = new CustomPopup(message);

        generateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                popup.showPopup();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: No one will write this code for you, mostly because no one knows what exactly you need to do. You need to show what you have tried and tells us what results you got that are a problem. Write some code, figure it out.

Comment: Without code, nobody can help you. Edit your question with some of your code so people can assist.

Comment: I've added what I've tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the following code any way you need. This is just an example of how you make and implement a custom `DialogFragment`.

He is the code I use. I find it quite flexible because you can create several similar dialogs for slightly different tasks. You will need to create a layout file - this gives you a great deal of flexibility on function and style.

My layout file is fragment_ok_cancel_dialog.

To satisfy your requirements just create your own layout file with all the elements in it you need (like your image).

In the Activity that calls the dialog you will need to implement the Listener.

```
implements OkCancelDialogFragment.OkCancelDialogListener
```

Another advantage is with my code you can change the title and the message to fit the needs of any Activity.

```
private void callMyDialog(){ 
    //Customize the title and message as needed
    String title = "This is my dialog title";
    String mess = "This is my dialog message";
    OkCancelDialogFragment dialog = OkCancelDialogFragment.newInstance(title, mess);
    dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "OkCancelDialogFragment2");
}
```

Now you need to implement the dialog callback in the Activity that calls the `DialogFragment`.

```
@Override
public void onFinishOkCancelDialog(boolean submit) {
    if(submit){
        // Do something positive
    }
    else{
        // Do something negative
    }
}
```

Now the code for the DialogFragment:

```
public class OkCancelDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private static final String ARG_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String ARG_MESSAGE = "message";

    Context context = null;

    private String title;
    private String message;
    private boolean submitData = false;

    private OkCancelDialogListener mListener;

    public OkCancelDialogFragment() {
    }

    public static OkCancelDialogFragment newInstance(String title, String message) {
        OkCancelDialogFragment fragment = new OkCancelDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_TITLE, title);
        args.putString(ARG_MESSAGE, message);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            title = getArguments().getString(ARG_TITLE);
            message = getArguments().getString(ARG_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle saveIntsanceState){

        context = getActivity();

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ok_cancel_dialog, null, false);
        final TextView titleView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        final TextView messView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);

        titleView.setText(title);
        messView.setText(message);

        builder.setView(rootView)
//                .setTitle(title)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok_button_dialog_title, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        submitData = true;
                        if(mListener == null) mListener = (OkCancelDialogListener) context;
                        mListener.onFinishOkCancelDialog(submitData);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        submitData = false;
                        if(mListener == null) mListener = (OkCancelDialogListener) context;
                        mListener.onFinishOkCancelDialog(submitData);
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            if(mListener == null) mListener = (OkCancelDialogListener) context;
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }


    public interface OkCancelDialogListener {
        void onFinishOkCancelDialog(boolean submit);
    }

}
```

Please note that .setTitle(title) is valid for API 23 or higher (or maybe API 21 or higher?).

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom xml layout

and in the OnClickListener of the button you can put this :

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        alertLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_CUSTOM_POPUP_LAYOUT, null);

        final AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alert.setView(alertLayout);
        TextView msg= alertLayout.findViewById(R.id.YOUR_TEXTVIEW_ID);

        alert.show();
```

after that you can add another button in your popup and set a listener on it to dismiss the layout after the click.